# How to choose coconut in supermarket?

Tags: shopping, coconut

I am an avid eater of coconut... Well, I would be if I had some decent coconut to begin with! It happened quite a few times that when I bought a coconut in a supermarket (you know the brown, ripe fruits? - well, here in Europe there is no abundance of fresh coconuts), and when I ate its content... it tasted like dish-soap (eeek!).
How can I be sure to select a coconut, which won't ruin my day?

Comment: Just to be sure: Did you learn the taste of coconut through eating fresh coconuts, or through eating [stuff with or including] processed [parts of] coconut? There tends to be quite a difference between, say, coconut milk, a Bounty bar, and cracking open a fresh coconut, and eating the flesh. Although "dish-soap" wouldn't be my immediate association and does sound wrong, the taste profile is definitely quite different, and can leave people wondering if this is how it should be.

Comment: related https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/32922/how-to-know-whether-a-coconut-is-ripe-or-rancid-before-buying

Comment: No i actually ate the real thing. Fresh as well. But the point is: sometimes here it really tastes like soap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those at the store should be heavy and 2/3 full of milk or more. So shake them and listen, and also judge the weight, holding them in one hand.

---

Once you buy a coconut, place it between a rock or three. Make one slice with a large heavy knife to remove the top and the top hull inside the outer hull. Pour out the milk and chill if you wish. Then cut the coconut in half. Scoop out the meat. It should be firm but soft. Place that on a plate or eat with your hands.

---

When harvesting, after dropping a bunch of coconuts, you select the ones whose outer hull is 1/3 to 1/4 brown. Those you sell locally. The green ones you take to the road to sell to the waiting trucks. Those are for shipment.

All extra coconuts should be saved for making coconut rum. The outer and inner hulls are saved for cooking and coconut charcoal. Any that drop from the tree and split open go into the rum also, or can be used as pig fodder.

Comment: I've edited this answer too, to put the answer to the actual question (how do I pick out a good one) up front. The rest... I edited for clarity and left it, but honestly, it's a little hard to see how it relates to the question at hand and I would consider removing it. The OP is buying coconuts in stores, not harvesting them. They're not going to be making their own rum. It's interesting information, but I might save it for a question that actually asks for it.